# TextView in HorizontalScrollView not scrolling automatically when text is added

Tags: android, xml, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a TextView that takes in Strings and I want the TextView to scroll to the last text added on the right automatically. The ScrollView works but I have to scroll manually to the last text added when it's out of the TextView's field of view. Please help.

```css
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through the use EditTextView instead of TextView and disabling focusEnabled by setting keyListener to null in order to achieve the behavior of a normal TextView and also scroll automatically like I wanted.